# didn't apply the css to pagination mvc

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, pagination, datatables

I'm creating a website using ASP.net MVC framework.in there using DataTable and used the relevant CSS and Jquery files.but my pagination like odd.it means there is not applied the css .DataTable is Generated Dynamically.
[my default Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU4lq.png)
However, i'm checking the inspect element what can I find the solution.
when changing the class name as a "dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers  **pagination**" ,expected result outcome.but it's tempory.
[After editing class name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL0bB.png)

i think should change  the jQuery file

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code? Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Maybe take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are saying here without any code but it seems you are having trouble applying pagination class. Have you tried setting `pagingType` to `simple_numbers`? So something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers"
    });
});
```

Please refer this documentation on it: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: i need to style pagination part.using jquery

Comment: It is simple to add css class via jQuery. Just use `$("#customers_paginate").addClass("pagination");` But I think there is something wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone supports me when I'm in Trouble.Finally, i found the error.
Datatable loads in dynamically using Jquery code and also class also generate automatically.So here is the Answer to my Problem

[Click here to see the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilBEm.png)